# How to assign file programatically for file upload control

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, bootstrap-4

I'd like to assign a file for file upload control manually, is it possible to assign file to file upload control, how can I do it in angularjs.

```
 <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
    <a href="#" class="close fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"
       style="float: none" hidden>&times;</a>
    <span class="btn btn-blue btn-sm btn-file" style="background: #e6e9ee">
      <span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span>
      <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
      <input type="file" id="importBtn" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel,.xlsx,.xls" 
             facultylistfile-model="empFile" name="...">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger fileinput-exists"
      data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Vetriselvan, what type of file you want to assign in fileupload

Comment: pdf,csv, excel file

Comment: wat error you get?

Comment: i am not yet tried  assign file to the file upload controller, i just asking how to do this